# PHP operators Why all fine?

Tags: php

My original code (with problem):

```
//......
$question_slug = str_slug($question->title);
if ( ($question_slug=='definition')){ 
        $question_slug == 'all';  // <= problem
}
dd($question_slug);
//.....
```

I made mistake (**==** instead **=**) => var `question_slug` didn`t change. But why all fine with code above, without any error/warning/notice? 
Question: why we can (interpreter allow) write like:

```
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 $question_slug == 'all';
 'all' == 'all';
```

Using it without assigment operator and  not in other constructions (`if`,etc.). Where it can be used?

Comment: There are IDEs and other tools that will yield a warning/error message for this kind of statement. The vanilla php runtime just isn't one of them.

Comment: Not that it would be a good idea, but someone might have overloaded the comparison operator with a method that has side effects. This might be one purely made-up situation in which such a statement might be intentional.

Comment: There is no overloading for the comparison-operator for objects (yet; maybe php7?)